# How do I make a Minecraft recipe that costs XP?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I want to program a Minecraft client-mod or server-plugin that adds a recipe for making a *Bottle o' Enchanting* with the following ingredients:

*1 glass bottle + **1 lvl of experience** → 1 Bottle o' Enchanting*

One possible implementation that I have thought of is to execute the command `/xp -1L player`, but I am unsure how to invoke that command from my Java code. Is there a better way?

How would you go about adding an experience-requiring recipe to Minecraft?

[image: how the crafting window ought to look]

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and how it's not working. Modding questions that are specific to one game don't typically do well here, I'd suggest asking on a Minecraft modding forum.

Comment: I made a big edit (with many thanks to [Nikolaii99](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/55902/nikolaii99)) that I think clarify the question enough to be reopened. I had to make some assumptions, so just to check: Does it still match what you wanted to ask?

Comment: I was using eclipse

Comment: Currently, with a basic mod, this is impossible. However, with reflection, ASM, and hard code, it might be possible

Comment: [I've kinda done it with ASM](https://github.com/eyeballcode/RandomUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/eyeball/randomutils/coremod/Transformer.java#L300-L482), see the code there. [Here is where the recipe is added](https://github.com/eyeballcode/RandomUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/eyeball/randomutils/crafting/CraftingModules.java#L14)

Comment: Pretty sure this can be done without ASM, I did exp related things in 1.6 or 1.7 with relative ease. ASM should be your last resort, coming in after "give up and weep in the corner" because of you do not already understand Java bytecode and how you can competely break the game workout knowing it, you should not be using ASM.